# Set the text of a textbox inside a duplicated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textbox

I have a master div which contains multiple divs and a textbox inside. Inside that textbox a user types content.

After the user is done typing the contents I am duplicating the entire master div. But when I duplicate the master div, I can only duplicate everything except the contents of the textbox inside.

The way I did this is copying the html of the master div in javascript. I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

The Master Div is the *createmain1* here

```
<div id="createmain1" class="createmainclass1">
  <div id="leftbox1">
    <!--<p>the preview left div</p>-->
    <div id="createmain1leftframe1" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
      <div id="createmain1leftframe2" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
        <div id="createmain1leftframe3" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
          <div id="createmain1leftframe4" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
            <textarea id="lefttext1" spellcheck="true" maxlength="500" wrap="hard" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'GillSansLightRegular'; overflow:hidden; resize:none; font-size:20px; border:none; height: 100%; background-color:transparent" placeholder="Enter Text Here"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightbox1">
    <!--<p>the preview right div</p>-->
    <div id="createmain1rightframe1" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
      <div id="createmain1rightframe2" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
        <div id="createmain1rightframe3" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
          <div id="createmain1rightframe4" style="height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
            <textarea id="righttext1" spellcheck="true" maxlength="500" wrap="hard" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'GillSansLightRegular'; overflow:hidden; resize:none; font-size:20px; border:none; height: 100%; background-color:transparent" placeholder="Enter Text Here"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The place where I am duplicating is

```
 <div id="finalimage" style="background-color:lightcoral" ></div>
```

JavaScript that I wrote is

```
$("#Preview").click(function () {
  var firstdiv = $("#createmain1").html();
  var lefttext = $("#lefttext1").val();
  $("#finalimage").css("height", "310px");
  $("#finalimage").css("width", "460px");
  $("#finalimage").html(firstdiv);
  $("#finalimage").children("#leftbox1").css("height", "300px");
  $("#finalimage").children("#leftbox1").css("width", "225px");
  $("#finalimage").children("#leftbox1").css("float", "left");
  $("#finalimage").children("#rightbox1").css("height", "300px");
  $("#finalimage").children("#rightbox1").css("width", "225px");
  $("#finalimage").children("#rightbox1").css("float", "left");
  $("#finalimage").children("#lefttext1").val(lefttext);
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, but there is no, and has never been, a 'textbox' element. Ever. It doesn't exist, despite a continued stream of people that seem to believe, inexplicably, otherwise. You can have `<input type="text" />`, or a `<textarea></textarea>`, but that's as close as there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks like is happening is that you are grabbing the first div here:

```
var firstdiv = $("#createmain1").html();
```

Add this code in to emulate the divs:

```
$("#finalimage").html(firstdiv);
```

And you aren't actually doing anything with it.

You also cannot replicate IDs. I would rebuild the divs in the new system with jQuery rather than simply copying the html from one to another.

EDIT:

I have included a jsfiddle example for you to check out. If you want to keep everything the same, you can simply use .find() to grab the text area and set the info.

http://jsfiddle.net/EqaLw/

Comment: You are right I am grabbing the html content of createmain1 and then simply copying inside finalimage. I couldn't think of any other way of doing it. I should probably take a different approach to this like ya'll mentioned. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: awesome...works beautifully.. Thanks a ton.. You almost had me worried there. Would have up'd your reputation if I could.

Answer (score 3):

as you are using jQuery - have you tried using the `.clone()` method?

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

also you are creating divs with duplicate `id` attribute which is not allowed.

the page above explains how to use clone() and recommends:

> Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: yes I tried .clone() method but it basically does the same as .html(). Clone method will create an object out of it and I still need to access the html content so that I can set it to the finalimage div. Also if you can suggest, how can I change id's of div after i copy it?

Comment: @nishan_vodoo `.clone()` does a lot more than `.html()` - it allows you to preserve event handlers bound with jQuery and jQuery data for elements